# Access eclipse plugin commandid value from class

Tags: eclipse, plugins

Is it possible to get the commandId value from the org.eclipse.ui.handlers extension point from the target class?

I would like to create a single class and have multiple commandId's call it.

Basically, I'm trying to create multiple menu items call a single class and based on the menu item perform a different task.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ExecutionEvent` passed to the handler `execute` method has a

```java
public Command getCommand()
```

method which returns you the `Command` being executed.

`Command` has:

```java
public String getId();
```

which returns the id.

Comment: Thanks greg for your answer here and others you have posted. You have been a big help in my learning eclipse development!